# firebase - Accessing child of of database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im new to Firebase and am having trouble access some nested JSON data. Here is my data structure:

[image]

In Samples I have a set of JSON data which I am trying to access. Previously I had the database setup so that there was no "users" subcategory and all the samples JSON data was in the root and the data was loading fine like this. Since creating parent categories i've had trouble trying to access the Samples data. Here is how i'm trying to reach it (using React):

```
componentWillMount() {  
    var db = firebase.database();
    var ref = db.ref('music-app-7a4d3').child("samples");
    ref.once('value')
        .then((snapshot) => {
            var samplesObject = snapshot.val();
            this.setState({
                samples: samplesObject
            });
        });
},
```

The `componentWillMount` function basically sets the initial state of the app with the objects found in samples. I'm a little bit lost as I thought I could access the next tier down by using the .child method but its not finding the data. Where am I going wrong here?

As requested heres an expanded view of my data:

[image]

Comment: could you provide data model example with your new architecture and also tell what part of that you want to grab.

Comment: updated @VladimirGabrielyan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var ref = db.ref('music-app-7a4d3/samples/your/awesome/subitem');
```

EDIT:
 try remove the `music-app-7a4d3` keep only this: `/samples/your/awesome/subitem`

Comment: tried that already like so 'var ref = db.ref('music-app-7a4d3/samples');' with no luck